# Undefined variable in script with circular includes (first script includes another which includes the first one)

Tags: php, include, undefined, require, circular-dependency

I'm dealing with a PHP application with what seems to have a peculiarity: One of its files (`helpers.php`) has a couple of functions that includes another file, and the included file (`db_connection.php`) includes the file that originally included it.

*helpers.php:*

```
<?php

function lineBreak()
{
    return "\n<br>\n";
}

function saveScoreToDB($score)
{
    //session_start(); // Already started

    $usuario_id = $_SESSION["usuario_id"];
    $etapa = $_SESSION["etapa"];

    try
    {
        $query_etapa = "SELECT id FROM etapas WHERE numero = $etapa";

        require_once "db_connection.php";

        // `$db_link` works perfectly fine here:
        $etapa_id = $db_link->query($query_etapa)->fetchColumn();

        $query_score = "INSERT INTO score
                            (
                                usuario_id,
                                etapa_id,
                                pontos
                            )
                                VALUES
                            (
                                $usuario_id,
                                $etapa_id,
                                $score
                            )";

        $db_link->query($query_score);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $_SESSION["error_message"] = $e->getMessage();
        header("Location: erro.php");
    }
}

function completeTest($redirectTo)
{
    unset($_SESSION["etapa"]);

    $usuarioId = $_SESSION["usuario_id"];

    // TODO: try/catch

    try
    {
        $queryEmailUsuario = "SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE id = $usuarioId";
        $queryNomeUsuario = "SELECT nome FROM usuarios WHERE id = $usuarioId";

        require_once "db_connection.php";

        // `$db_link` does *not* work here. Why?
        $emailUsuario = $db_link->query($queryEmailUsuario)->fetchColumn();
        $nomeUsuario = $db_link->query($queryNomeUsuario)->fetchColumn();

        // Routine to send email using the variables above
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

*db_connection.php:*

```
<?php

require_once "db_credentials.php";
require_once "helpers.php";

// Variables used here come from `db_credentials.php`
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;port=3307;charset=utf8;";

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false
];

try
{
    $db_link = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error connecting to the database.";
    echo lineBreak();
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo lineBreak();
    echo lineBreak();
}
```

Notice how in the first script variable `$db_link` is used in two different functions, both of which include the file where this variable is defined. Within the first function (`saveScoreToDB`), the variable is available and the function works fine; but within the second (`completeTest`) it is not available and I get an undefined variable error.

Why is that? How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `require_once()` works because that's the "once", but it's only in-scope in that single function call, so `$db_link` gets tossed out at the end of the function call and is never seen again. You can change that to `require()`, but creating a new connection for every single function call is... not going to work out well in the long run.

Ideally you create the connection *once* and then pass it in via parameters where it is needed, eg:

```php
require_once('db_credentials.php');

saveScoreToDB($score, $db_link);
completeTest($redirectTo, $db_link)
```

But that might get a bit tedious, right? Well this is where classes become useful.

```php
class MyThing {

  protected $db;

  public function __construct(\PDO $db) {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function saveScoreToDB($score) {
    $this->db->prepare(...);
  }

  public function completeTest($redirectTo) {
    $this->db->prepare(...);
  }
}

$thing = new Mything($db_link);
$thing->saveScoreToDB(42);
$thing->completeTest('yes');
```

Comment: Excellent aproach as well as the explanation. Thanks.